# useContext only works in stateless functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get to grips with the new `useContext` function in React. Works great in stateless functionality components. For example:

```
import React from 'react';
import LocaleContext from '../LocaleContext';

const Link = ({ text, url }) => {
  const locale = useContext(LocaleContext);

  return (
    <a href={`/${locale}/${url}`}>
      {text}
    </a>
  );
};

export default Link;
```

I also want to use `useContext` in stateful components, and even non React functions, but when I do so, I get the following error:

`Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component.`

The message seems simple enough to understand, but is this really true? I can only use it in a stateless functional component? If so, it seems kind of pointless to me, because it's super easy to use a simple HOC or the traditional method of:

```
<Locale Consumer>
  {locale => (
    ...
  )}
</LocaleConsumer>
```

So what gives here? I have the latest version of every package in my project. Not sure if it matters but I'm developing a NextJS site here.

Comment: If you call `useContext` it stores a reference to the functional component it gets called in, and then if the context gets updated, the functional component gets refreshed (called again). If you call it outside of a functional component, it makes little sense as you won't receive any updates.

Comment: *If so, it seems kind of pointless to me, because it's super easy to use a simple HOC or the the traditional method of* - tasks that are supposed to be solved with hooks previously were solved with HOCs like recompose. Now there's less boilerplate.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is what the error says. React hooks aren't available in class components. Due to differences between class components and function components, hooks cannot be used with the former.

As [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html#classes-confuse-both-people-and-machines) says,

> Hooks let you use more of React’s features without classes. Conceptually, React components have always been closer to functions. Hooks embrace functions, but without sacrificing the practical spirit of React. Hooks provide access to imperative escape hatches and don’t require you to learn complex functional or reactive programming techniques.

Hooks are supposed to address common use cases that are specific to class components which couldn't be previously implemented with stateless functional components alone. Functional components aren't stateless since React 16.8 and are allowed to have a state and trigger own updates.

As for [`useContext` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext),

> When the provider updates, this Hook will trigger a rerender with the latest context value.

It would be messed up in class component due to difference between functional and class components. Component function is called each time the component is rendered:

```
const Foo = props => {

  const context = useContext(Context);
  // use context
}
```

There's no place in class component that would behave the same way except `render` function. And if lifecycle-specific tasks go to `render` function, this means that a class was a wrong choice, and class component needs to be refactored to a function. A counterpart to `useContext` in class components is [`contextType`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#classcontexttype), which is currently restricted to single context.

For multiple contexts it's still required to receive them through context `Consumer` inside `render`, or as props from higher-order component wrapper:

```
const contextsHOC = (contexts = {}) => Comp => (
  props => {
    const contextProps = {};
    for (const prop in contexts) {
       // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
       contextProps[prop] = React.useContext(contexts[prop]);
    }
    return <Comp {...props} {...contextProps}/>;
  }
);

@contextsHOC({ bar: BarContext, baz: BazContext });
export default class FooComponent extends Component {
  // contexts are mapped to this.props.bar and this.props.baz
  ...
}

// or

class FooComponent extends Component { ... }
export default contextsHOC({ ... })(FooComponent);
```

Passing contexts as props allows for additional optimization with `PureComponent` or `shouldComponentUpdate`.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful explanation. I did look at contextType for class components, but currently have 2 or 3 HOCs for context on some of my classes, so couldn't restrict myself to a single context.

My quest to use `useContext` in a regular non React function was simply as a store. For example I store the locale for the site e.g. `en` in a context provider. I want to be able to access that data from a helper function, but I guess it's not possible with `useContext`.

Comment: You're welcome. No, no chances to work for random helpers because hooks are magical and depend on how components that use them are rendered.

Comment: Is there a way to have multiple context using `contextType` now? Or is this last remark still valid today? If that's still not possible, what would you recommend for multiple contexts in class components?

Comment: @cglacet The development of class component API has stopped in favour of functional components, no improvements of contextType are expected. Wrapping a class with functional HOC that uses useContext and passing them as props is a good way to do this. Something like was done in another answer but it's not limited to one useContext, there can be many of them. This is beneficial in the long run because a class can be made PureComponent and skip unnecessary context updates; an optimization that isn't possible by using useContext or contextType in the same component they are consumed.

Comment: I've seen the other answer, it seems fine to me I was just hopping for a less verbose solution but if no improvements are to be expected I will happily use this solution. Are you part of react-native's team or did you saw a discussion about class component being discontinued? Why the function API is promoted instead of the class API?

Comment: @cglacet I've updated the post with an example. Functional API is coherent with FP principles that the team heavily supports. I'm not a part of the team and haven't seen deprecation discussions yet but noticed that class-related issues don't receive much attention in React repo anymore, while hooks rapidly became a standard for modern React.  Classes are too common for now but I expect them to become deprecated later, similarly to ES5 comps. Class components have inborn problems with types (specifically TS) that don't exist with functions, I'm quite sure this was one of reasons to ditch them.

Comment: Just wanted to mention that you can in fact use React hooks in class-components, if you use this library: https://github.com/salvoravida/react-universal-hooks I've been using it for a couple of years, and it works fine.

Answer (score 17):

If you really want to use classes (i actually came from Angular and i still prefer use classes) you can workaround easily like that:

```
class ComponentImpl extends React.Component<any> {
  constructor(props?) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        CounterButton: <button onClick={() => {this.props.appContext.setCount(this.props.appContext.count + 5)}}>App Counter + 5</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export function Component() {
  let appContext = useContext(AppContext);

  return <ComponentImpl appContext={appContext}></ComponentImpl>
};
```

And you just use it: `<Component></Component>`

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I am not sure if this is the best practice, but it does help me a lot!

Comment: This looks very natural to me, it's as common as decorators can be. The `Component` is a decorator that simply extract context to inject it as a props. You could even patch existing component without the user noticing this change.

Answer (score 1):

`useContext` is a **hook** that **consumes a context** and can only be used in **functional components**.

If you want to consume context in **class components**, you will need to look at alternative methods such as Consumer Component, [official docs for this here](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)