# React Native Context, how to share context beetwing multiple nested files and components

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-context

I'm quiete new to react native, and im stuck on passing context between components in different files
basically im building login flow following the react navigation auth-flow https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/
my scenario looks as follow:

in App.js
a stack screen with Login/Register/Home, showing Login/Register or Home based on login status
the Home Screen is made by a component which is a drawer, using a custom drawer and two component (Home and About)

```
//VARIOUS IMPORT    
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const HeaderOption = () => ({
  headerShown: false,
  // animationTypeForReplace: state.isSignout ? 'pop' : 'push',
});

const AppStack = createStackNavigator();

const AuthContext = createContext();

//THE DRAWER FOR HOME
function DrawerNavigator(props) {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Home"
      drawerContent={(props) => MyDrawer(props)}
    >
      <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="About" component={About} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}
//MAIN APP
export default function App({ navigation }) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(
    (prevState, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case 'RESTORE_TOKEN':
          return {
            ...prevState,
            userToken: action.token,
            isLoading: false,
          };
        case 'SIGN_IN':
          return {
            ...prevState,
            isSignout: false,
            userToken: action.token,
          };
        case 'SIGN_OUT':
          return {
            ...prevState,
            isSignout: true,
            userToken: null,
          };
      }
    },
    {
      isLoading: true,
      isSignout: false,
      userToken: null,
    }
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch the token from storage then navigate to our appropriate place
    const bootstrapAsync = async () => {
      let userToken;

      try {
        userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');
      } catch (e) {
      }

     
      dispatch({ type: 'RESTORE_TOKEN', token: userToken });
    };

    bootstrapAsync();
  }, []);

  const authContext = useMemo(
    () => ({
      signIn: async (data) => {
        // LOGIN PROCEDURE

        dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_IN', token: 'dummy-auth-token' });
      },
      signOut: () => dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_OUT' }),
      signUp: async (data) => {
        // SUBSCRIBE PROCEDURE

        dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_IN', token: 'dummy-auth-token' });
      },
    }),
    []
  );

  if (state.isLoading) {
    // We haven't finished checking for the token yet
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Loading</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={authContext}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <AppStack.Navigator initialRouteName="Login">
          {state.userToken == null ? (
            <>
              <AppStack.Screen
                name="Login"
                component={LoginScreen}
                options={HeaderOption}
              />
              <AppStack.Screen
                name="Register"
                component={RegisterScreen}
                options={HeaderOption}
              />
            </>
          ) : (
            <AppStack.Screen
              name="HomeApp"
              component={DrawerNavigator}
              options={HeaderOption}
            />
          )}
        </AppStack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

in LoginScreen.js
the effective login screen (which is showed at app startup if not logged in)

```
//import

export default function LoginScreen(props) {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const { signIn } = useContext(AuthContext);

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,

        backgroundColor: Constants.MAIN_GREEN,
      }}
    >
      <View style={{ ...styles.container }}>
        <StatusBar hidden={true} />
        <View style={{ ...styles.logoContainer }}>
          <Image
            style={styles.logoIcon}
            source={require('../assets/logo_popeating_amp.png')}
          />
        </View>

        <View style={{ ...styles.inputContainer }}>
          <Image
            style={styles.inputIcon}
            source={require('../assets/mail.png')}
          />
          <TextInput
            autoFocus={true}
            placeholder="Email address"
            onChangeText={(email) => setEmail(email)}
            value={email}
            label="Email"
            style={styles.inputs}
            keyboardType={'email-address'}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={{ ...styles.inputContainer }}>
          <Image
            style={styles.inputIcon}
            source={require('../assets/password.png')}
          />
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Password"
            onChangeText={(password) => setPassword(password)}
            value={password}
            secureTextEntry={true}
            label="Password"
            style={styles.inputs}
          />
        </View>
        <TouchableHighlight
          style={[styles.buttonContainer, styles.loginButton]}
          onPress={() => signIn({ email, password })}
          underlayColor={Constants.HI_COLOR}
        >
          <Text style={styles.loginText}>LOGIN</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>

        <TouchableHighlight
          style={styles.buttonContainer}
          onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('HomeApp')}
          underlayColor={Constants.HI_COLOR}
        >
          <Text>Forgot your password?</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>

        <TouchableHighlight
          style={styles.buttonContainer}
          onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Register')}
          underlayColor={Constants.HI_COLOR}
        >
          <Text>Register</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  //styles
});
```

in DrawerContent.js
the drawer for the home which contain a link to Home, a link to About, a link to Logout

in Home.js
the main page which is the initialroute of the Drawer

every time i try to start the app
the error is
**Unhandled promise rejection: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: AuthContext**

it seems LoginScreen cant access AuthContext, how can i have AuthContext available to other components between files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place the context creation in a separate file

```
//AuthContext.js
const AuthContext = createContext();
export default AuthContext;
```

In app.js you can simply import this and use this

```
import AuthContext from './AuthContext.js';
```

You can do the same for login.js as well
Then it will work as expected.

Comment: Thank you! it works on login but if i do the same for the DrawerContent i got an error, Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of the function component.

Comment: As the error says your drawercontent is a class component, you can change it to a functional component if possible or do a workaround in the answers like the below question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54695835/usecontext-only-works-in-stateless-functional-component

Comment: This is my DrawerContent (which is called by MyHome which is called by App)


`import AuthContext from '../AuthContext';
const MyDrawer = (props) => {
  const { signOut } = useContext(AuthContext);
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View
        style={{ height: 150, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}
      >
       

        <TouchableOpacity style={{ marginTop: 20 }} onPress={() => signOut()}>
          <Text>Logout</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
export default MyDrawer;`

Comment: strange, its a functional component so it should work as expected

Comment: i have a useEffect in main app, can it be? but without useEffect i cant check if the user is already logged in at startup, also all the function are in a useMemo which is passed to AuthContext... maybe im getting a bit confused

Comment: No that cant be an issue, can you try that in some other screen and check whether you get the same error ?

Comment: i tried i lots of way, maybe i made things more confused than necessary, but it looks i cant access the signin and signout function that are in App from other files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218147/discussion-between-guruparan-giritharan-and-popeating).